# How do I get from the universal product of the tensor product to other definitions.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, universal-property

I was wondering how you can "derive" the common (or "classical") definition of the tensor product before the universal property was established (I think there is no need to repeat it here), i.e. a multilinear map of the cartesian product of $r$ copies of a vector space $V$ and $s$ copies of the dual space $V^*$ into, let's say, $\mathbb{R}$, from the universal defintion?

Comment: The universal definition is not constructive. I don't see what you can do besides show that the old construction satisfies the universal property.

Comment: But how did one get from the old definition to the new one? It wasn't simply an educated guess, was it?

Comment: That seems like a historical question (and different from the one you asked originally)! My guess is that people were using these universal properties for a long time. Until the explosion of algebraic objects in the 50s-60s there probably wasn't a huge need to formalize it.